# How to automate the Junit test written using Talend routines using Jenkins?

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, talend, routines

We have a Talend job, in which we have written a routines with our own customized function to verify the functionality using Junit Assert methods.

How we can automate this Talend routine test using Jenkins? somehow we need to fail the build if the Assert is failing.

Talend supports running tests only when we write the component based testing using Create Test by right clicking the component. But our case is something that we dont have component specific testing.

Appreciate it for any help on this?

Comment: I can't give you what you want but we had a similar problem and decided to create a separate java project that we build into a "library". We import that with the tLibraryLoad component.

Comment: @borst.philipp : Thanks, let me try that.. will it run the test cases at the time of Jenkins build?

Comment: sorry, I didn't see your comment when I last checked stackoverflow. Our unit tests will run when we build the library. We have not linked the creation of the "code library" to the build of the Talend jobs yet (but it's on our short-list).

Comment: I solved this problem using test jobs, writing assertion results using tAssert.
Then, I run test jobs nightly using command line, and then parse the logs, extract tAssert and generate manually a junit test report, which is handled by Jenkins.
The problem is that Studio is slow and you have to wait for jobs to open endlessly while you work on your jobs, and then you have to maintain them.
I prefer using pure jUnit tests in Studio now.